# How to forward an email to external URL

Tags: theming

I would like to create a page that will automatically forward to an external site? Similar to what bitly, tinyurl do. So when people type example.com/page in address bar, site will automatically take them to mysite.com? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you can just create a URL redirect with [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect), and send to an external URL. No need to create a node.